# Let's get critical: Dec 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Japanese Language Stack Exchange](http://japanese.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: How rude, I'm always critical!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [What does "Ｘの一つにＹがある” mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13249/what-does-%ef%bc%b8%e3%81%ae%e4%b8%80%e3%81%a4%e3%81%ab%ef%bc%b9%e3%81%8c%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b%e2%80%9d-mean)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What does おくれ mean in this context?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13334/what-does-%e3%81%8a%e3%81%8f%e3%82%8c-mean-in-this-context)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [What does 忘れたい人 mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13267/what-does-%e5%bf%98%e3%82%8c%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84%e4%ba%ba-mean)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [The use of でも and ででも in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13463/the-use-of-%e3%81%a7%e3%82%82-and-%e3%81%a7%e3%81%a7%e3%82%82-in-this-sentence)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [かわいい　meaning care for](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13271/%e3%81%8b%e3%82%8f%e3%81%84%e3%81%84%e3%80%80meaning-care-for)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Figurative use of 空ける?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13278/figurative-use-of-%e7%a9%ba%e3%81%91%e3%82%8b)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Dropping から when modifying a noun](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13418/dropping-%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89-when-modifying-a-noun)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How do the two が in もう止まらない　あなたがあなたのことが恋しい work?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13378/how-do-the-two-%e3%81%8c-in-%e3%82%82%e3%81%86%e6%ad%a2%e3%81%be%e3%82%89%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84%e3%80%80%e3%81%82%e3%81%aa%e3%81%9f%e3%81%8c%e3%81%82%e3%81%aa%e3%81%9f%e3%81%ae%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8%e3%81%8c%e6%81%8b%e3%81%97%e3%81%84-work)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [詰まらないとは詰まるから作りました？](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13488/%e8%a9%b0%e3%81%be%e3%82%89%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84%e3%81%a8%e3%81%af%e8%a9%b0%e3%81%be%e3%82%8b%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e4%bd%9c%e3%82%8a%e3%81%be%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%ef%bc%9f)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [What is the connection between volitional よう form and であろう](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13448/what-is-the-connection-between-volitional-%e3%82%88%e3%81%86-form-and-%e3%81%a7%e3%81%82%e3%82%8d%e3%81%86)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)

---